# Login servlet for angular authorization

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets

Is it a bad or good idea to use java servlet for angular authorization?
for example:

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.login(....);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the requirements. For simple solution you could use it. For something more advanced you probably would need to use some framework e.g. Spring.

Comment: I want to secure rest services & websockets